# linking two or more domains with one website

Tags: domain

I have two domains each registered with different registrars. I have domainA.com linked with a website on someServer. Now I want to make domainB.com links to the website domainA.com.

How can I do that?

Note: I`m a beginner with web hostings and domains.

Comment: What  web server  you using ?  and OS ?

Comment: the web server that my website is hosted on is godaddy. and it is on a linux server. the other domain is registered with a company in Egypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point the domain at the same server, and add it to the current virtual host configuration on the server.

Comment: How can I do that? I`m new to hosting and domains.

Comment: and how can I access the virtual host configuration file on the godaddy hosting?

Comment: It's kind of difficult to say, seeing as how you've given us almost no information.

Comment: ok, what info do you need?

Comment: The web server configuration. Or at least just the `<VirtualHost>` directives.

Comment: I don`t have access to the virtual host configuration file I guess!! do you know how to access it on godaddy server?

Comment: Nope. Never touched 'em.

Comment: how long does it take to activate the NS update?

Comment: It's probably within minutes. Trickling down to the ISP DNS servers can take a while though, if it's a domain move.

Comment: The domain that I updated its NS is registered through a company in Egypt, it`s one of those new Arabic domains. And the NS I added are my website that is hosted on godaddy. Does this take time to be active?

Comment: Is it a completely new domain?

Comment: the Arabic, yes. the one on godaddy is owned for about 8 years.

Comment: Then it will be picked up as soon as someone looks it up.

Answer (score 0):

If have to point the dns entries of the 2nd domain on the dns server you have.
Since the ip of the web server is the same, you have to use a different port

Comment: No, this is completely incorrect.